# Pointer problem using Vector containing structs

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I am currently really stuck on how to solve the following problem:

```
struct node {
    int a;
    node* b;
}
```

I will have two root nodes without parents and then to more nodes pointing to their parents

```
vector<node> IholdAllTheNodes;

node noparent1; <--- these get returned from a method
node noparent2;

IholdAllTheNodes.pushback(noparent1);
IholdAllTheNodes.pushback(noparent2);

node withparent1; <---- i am happily points to noparent1
node withparent2; <-----i am happily points to noparent2
```

No problems up to here all working awesomely

```
IholdAllTheNodes.pushback(withparent1) <<<< oops this causes all the pointers to move.
```

now the withparent nodes are no longer pointing to their parents because I have moved them.

My question is simply how do I add more nodes to my vector of nodes without moving the pointers of the original nodes. (I cant get a fixed size for the vector)

if anyone has the time to explain, why even though pushback is adding to the end of the vector list is the location of the previous information changing?

Comment: You really call your node members `a` and `b`?

Comment: I must question that it's "all working awesomely" when you misspelt even the standard library function names - it should be `push_back()`. Your code can't even compile...

Comment: was an example, wasn't going to compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you store nodes by value in vector. They are copied, potentially many times. Each time a node will be placed in different memory address. As result you'll receive different pointers to it, and old pointers will point to invalid location.

As other answers suggested, use any kind of pointers to store your nodes in vector. I would recommend `boost::ptr_vector<node>` or `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<node> >`

**EDIT:**

Just to disagree with `reserve` recommendations:

It's dangerous. You need to put large bold warnings in all possible places so people who'll modify this code in the future cannot omit it. Because when you'll add more than `MAX_SIZE` elements to your vector, your space ship will end burning on Sun. In this case I would recommend to use `boost::array` since it's fixed size (so making your assumption more obivious) and catches buffer overflow at least in Debug builds

Comment: For the record: I disagree with the term `reserve recommendations`. I felt the need to give a relatively complete answer - including the standard library features in this area. I do agree with you that with this kind of linked datastructures, using pointers all the way down is vastly superior

Answer (score 2):

You could call **[reserve](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html#2)**

```
IholdAllTheNodes.reserve(MAX_SIZE);
```

up front to avoid reallocation. It requires you to know MAX_SIZE up front.

Alternatively,

- **suggested**: make it a [Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html)
- make it a `std::vector<shared_ptr<node> >` (similar but less efficient)
- make it a `std::vector<node*>` (similar but tedious and error-prone)
- **suggested**: avoid using pointers if you can. Address the nodes by `size_t` (*integer*) index into `IholdAllTheNodes` instead

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to use `reverse` to resolve this problem. Most probably it's a temporary solution (if any) that will work up to the next modification.

Comment: @Andy T: I don't suggest _reverse_ [sic]. I don't even suggest **reserve**! I just point out that the standard provides it: the standard (see, e.g. the linked page) is also very precise on when a std::vector is allowed to reallocate. It could be more than enough. Anyways, I was very explicit in what I'm suggesting as solutions instead :)

Comment: it was typo of course, I couldn't edit my comment because SO doesn't allow it for 5 mins or after another comment, and you was fast :) about `reserve` I explained in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Call `IholdAllTheNodes.reserve()` with a specific size, and it will guarantee that further insertions won't invalidate the pointers until such reserved ammount is reached.

Comment: @K: it appears you agree with me :)

Comment: @sehe: I even gave you that +1